# Hydroponic/Vertical farm system historical sensor data

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, agriculture

I'm working on Machine Learning project to improve/automate hydroponics farming systems. Is there any datasets covering crop yields in vertical/hydroponic farming setups ? Any hints or tips on how find such data will be highly appreciated.

Comment: sir medchedli the github link is not working for the datasets

Comment: @SWAPNILV Sorry the link is no longer accessible. PlantOS team deleted the git repo that contains the dataset. Maybe you can reach to them directly and ask for the dataset if they still have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plant OS a research group in Malaysia involved in Open Agriculture Initiative works published their first datasets on Github: https://github.com/plantOS/plant-os/tree/master/datasets

Comment: Sorry the link is no longer accessible. PlantOS team deleted the git repo that contains the dataset

Answer (score 2):

There are range of useful datasets. [plant-image-analysis.org](https://www.plant-image-analysis.org/dataset) is site compiling a list of publicly available datasets. Another list of comprehensive datasets are provided by [PlantCV](https://plantcv.danforthcenter.org/pages/data.html).

The quality and size of the data varies with some having ground truth, while others include tens of GBs worth of images. The parts of the plants also vary, with a few examining the roots while others focus on the shoots.

Useful approaches for extracting data include using the image classification developed by [PlantCV](https://github.com/danforthcenter/plantcv) themselves or by training your own neural network with [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

We are using these resources in our community project, [Smart Digital Garden](https://sdg.protohaus.org/), and the research project, [Veleda](https://veleda.io/), built on top of it.