# Hydroponics/ vertical farming dataset and techniques

Tags: data-request, agriculture

I am working on a Machine Learning project to improve/automate hydroponics farming systems. Are there any datasets covering crop yields in vertical/hydroponic farming setups? Any hints or tips on how to find such data will be highly appreciated.

Comment: either of these have something useful? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10893/1511 --- https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/11974/1511